# Why is this forEach loop nesting?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, foreach

Apologies for the poor code.. ridiculous compatibility on this one is testing my Vanilla JS metal:

I need to wrap each header and its sibling nodes (until the next header is reached) in a div. Why is the wrap function creating nested wrapper divs (labeled 'section)?

Initial state:

```
<h1></h1>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

For example, desired result:

```
<div class="section">
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Current result:

```
<div class="section">
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <div class="section">
    <h2></h2>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, the bigger the array of sibling nodes, the deeper the nesting gets. I know it's something simple but I can't wrap (pun intended) my head around it.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
// Filter for grouping like elements together
var getNextUntil = function (elem, selector, group) {
  // Setup siblings array and get next sibling
  var siblings = [];
  var next = elem.nextElementSibling;
  // Loop through all siblings
  while (next) {
      var isClass = next.className.split(' ').some(function (c) {
          var re = new RegExp(selector);
          return re.test(c);
      });
      // Check if grouping is set
      if (group == false) {
          // If the matching selector is found
          if (isClass == true) break;
           // Otherwise, push to array              
      } else {
          if (isClass == false) break;
      }
      siblings.push(next);
      // Get the next sibling
      next = next.nextElementSibling;    
  }
  return siblings;
};
var headers = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(headers, function(el, i){
  el.classList.add('header');
  var sibs = getNextUntil(el,'header', false);
  var section = document.createElement('div');
  section.className = 'section';
  function wrap(el, wrapper) {
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);
    wrapper.appendChild(el);
  }

  wrap(el,section);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(sibs, function(el, i){
    section.appendChild(el);
  })

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please show the initial state, before any js run...

Comment: @MrJ question edited, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but code below accomplishes your stated goal with Vanilla JavaScript using the same functionality you are using in terms of interoperability.

```js
const headers = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'];
// reference to the parent element
let parent = document.getElementById('within');
// use STATIC DOM NodeList - selects all direct children of the parent
let withinParent = document.querySelectorAll('#within > *');

for (let child of withinParent) {
  // A header will create a new div
  if (headers.includes(child.nodeName.toLowerCase())) {
    if (wrapper) parent.appendChild(wrapper);
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.classList.add('section');
    // this is the header element
    wrapper.appendChild(child);
    continue;
  }
  if (child.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT') {
    // Add elements until we find another header
    wrapper.appendChild(child);
  }
}
// include final div for the final header
parent.appendChild(wrapper);
console.log(parent);
```

```css
.section {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id='within'>

  <h1>Header 1</h1>
  <p>Sibling 1</p>
  <p>Sibling 2</p>
  <p>Sibling 3</p>

  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <p>Sibling 1</p>
  <p>Sibling 2</p>

  <h3>Header 3</h3>
  <p>Sibling 1</p>
  <p>Sibling 2</p>

  <h4>Header 4</h4>
  <p>Sibling 1</p>
  <p>Sibling 2</p>
  <p>Sibling 3</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Ah brilliant stuff, thanks! That's pretty much exactly what I need and a much cleaner way of writing it. Just one question.. how would you go about inserting each wrapper div back into the DOM in the same place as the original elements were. Essentially mirroring jQuery's wrap() function, rather than appending to body?

Comment: In the first line of the `.forEach()` loop do `let parentNode = el.parentNode()` and rather than `document.body.appendChild()` it would be `parentNode.appendChild()` ... easy peasy.

Comment: Sorry, still having trouble with this. That works perfectly.. until there are multiple elements inside a parent div. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kettultim/jxhr369c/22/ - I don't know why but I'm having a serious mental block with this.

Comment: @kettultim - well that's probably because I did a terrible job of explaining. Please review my edited answer. The code has been rewritten to use static NodeList which will make your life easier. I've also commented every important bit of code for you. Hope this is more helpful.

Comment: Not your fault at all.. I just need to go back to JS 101 apparently as I've relied on jQuery for far too long. This is amazing - I finally understand it. Thank you so much!

Comment: glad to help. Have fun with all this.